# How to convert two arrays into an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays, one for the players names :

```
players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack',...]
```

And another for the points of the players :

```
points = [23,13,18,...]
```

And I would like to know if it was possible to (not manually) transform this two arrays into an object that would look like this :

```
players_results = {
    'John': { point: 23},
    'Paul': { point: 13},
    'Jack': { point: 18},
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) for achieving your required result.

`fromEntries` takes an array of arrays (*the nested array contains two values, 1st one is the key and the 2nd one is the value*) and then converts it to an object. Try this-

```js
const players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack'];
const points = [23,13,18];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  players_name.map((name, i) => ([name, {point: points[i]}]))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

***Note:** This is not a good idea to use a `name` as the key of an object. Names might be similar for different people. Use a unique value as a key instead.*

Answer (score 6):

```js
const players_name = ['John', 'Paul', 'Jack']
const points = [23, 13, 18]

const result = players_name.reduce((prev, item, i) => {
  prev[item] = {
    point: points[i]
  }
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `Array#forEach`

```js
const players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack']
const points = [23,13,18]

players_results ={};

players_name.forEach((a,i)=>{
  players_results[a] = {point:points[i]}
})

console.log(players_results)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack'];
    
const points = [23,13,18];

const players_results = {}

players_name.forEach((data, index) => {
  players_results[data] = {
      point: points[index]
    }
});

console.log(players_results);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you consider this is manually or not but you can use this function:

```js
let players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack'];

let points = [23,13,18];

function tabToObject(tab1, tab2) {
  let lengthMin = Math.min(tab1.length, tab2.length);
  let returnObject = new Object();
  for (let i = 0; i < lengthMin; i++) {
    returnObject[tab1[i]] = {point: tab2[i]};
  }
  return returnObject;
}

console.log(tabToObject(players_name, points))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***reduce*** array method [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack'];
const points = [23,13,18];

const object = players_name.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  acc[cur] = {points: points[index]};
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do this to my mind

```
players_name.forEach((name, index) => {
    players_results[name] = {point: points[index]}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Square bracket notation is a very helpful syntax that can help get out of nasty situation with ease when using JavaScript Objects.

```
var players_name = ['John','Paul','Jack'];
var points = [23,13,18];

function arrayToObject(arr1,arr2){
  obj = {};
  for(i in arr1){;
    obj[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
  }
  return obj;
}

x = arrayToObject(players_name, points)
console.log(x);
```